# ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a question.
views/admins/show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title , "施設") %>


  <p><%= @admin.name  %></p>
  <p><%= @admin.place %></p>
  <p><%= @admin.address %></p>
  <p><%= @admin.content  %></p>
<%= @dogs.each do |dog| %>
  <p><%= dog.name %></p>
  <p><%= dog.age  %></p>
  <p><%= dog.personality  %></p>
  <p><%= dog.breed  %></p>
  <p><%= dog.content  %></p>
<% end %>
```

and admins_controller

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :authenticate_admin! , only:[:show]    
 def show
    #@admin = current_admin
    @admin=Admin.find(params[:id])
    @dogs = @admin.dogs
 end
end
```

When I watch the show.html.erb, The page's last sentence contains ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy.
Why do it contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have the equals here, which tells rails to output it

```
<%= @dogs.each do |dog| %>
```

Make it

```
<% @dogs.each do |dog| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

They hold the relation between `Admin` and `Dog`. It also provides many methods which can be used on the related Dog objects. Refer this for more details: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html

Comment: Thank you! I did <% @dogs.each do |dog| %> and fixed it!